# How can I dismiss alert dialog with yes no option in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I try to dismiss the alert dialog with yes/no question. After I dismiss the alert dialog by choosing yes, the spinner will display. I try many times but it does not work. My code is below.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setMessage("Do you want to send it for object recognition?")
       .setCancelable(true)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               dialog.dismiss();

                           }
                       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

what actually do you want? you use

```
 dialog.dismiss();
 mSpinner.show();
```

it dismiss the dialog and i think you are using  mSpinner.show()  to show your spinner ( there are no such method spinner.shoe() to show spinner) `dialog.dismiss` is sufficient to dismiss the dialog. just call it in `onClick` method of yes and no button.

Comment: check it properly. it cant be possible . might be there are several dialog opened. if you click on dismiss what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Spinner has no method like **show()**.

see [Android Spinner Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly In the onClick method of "YES" button set the adapter for the spinner--

```
  private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter; 
  private Spinner spinner;  
 adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(EmailView.this,
            R.array.array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then after doing this dismiss the dialog--

```
    dialog.cancel();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem is the alert dialog. I cannot dismiss it. :(

Comment: Use dialog.cancel(); after setting the spinner in "yes" button.

Comment: You want to open spinner on "yes" Button of dialog..then set the spinner on "yes" button as i have told you...after that use   dialog.cancel();  on the click of the spinner item like this--- spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {      
 dialog.cancel();
 }
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {     dialog.cancel();
 }});

Answer (score 0):

If you will leave your onClick method empty, it will dismiss the alert dialog.